# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74eaaba0 in tid 5938

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdBpu.png)
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x14

The Above error is coming only when the API is being called on the server using a retrofit. THe snippet code is mentioned below.

```kotlin
var responseResult: Call < String > ;

responseResult = apiNetworkService ? .postAPIStringServerResponse(
    restAPI,
    "Header",
    createRequestBody_Retrofit(params)
  ) !!


  responseResult.enqueue(object: Callback < String > {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call < String > , response: Response < String > ) {
      response.let {
        var orignal_json = JSONObject();

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
          mInterface.onResponse(it.body().toString(), requestCode, params)
        }

      }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call < String > , e: Throwable) {

      try {
        mCallback.onResponse(e.message, requestCode, params)
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStack()
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Is this error occurs due to custom code - i.e. some apk you built or it's something inherited from Android OS?, please add the code that is causing this error.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes, this is only happening when the retrofit Api is being called. And, in Android latest OS it is working fine. But, it is having the issue with Android <=6.0

Comment: All details must be in the question. You have to provide enough information in order for understand the whole situation.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes, I have tried to the snippet code where the actual problem and it is happening when the API call from the Main thread. Only below Android OS version 6.0. It is not happening in newer devices. Also, sometime it works and randomly is getting crashed.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdBpu.png

Comment: +1 and thank you for improve your question. It might be possible due to the data is receiving? - maybe it's some missing settings for compatibility. Check this [entry](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3043) on Github. if it doesn't help, please search `retrofit api android crashes` on Google - that's how I found the previous link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, read the "related" questions to your question. These related questions are next to the body of your question - see if those questions and answers help you. Keep updated your question with what you have found. Hope you find the answer :)

Comment: Still, the same I have update compileOption as mentioned in the comment but it is working and able to navigate some section but suddenly it is getting crash ... giving the same error..

Comment: A: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x14

Comment: I have sees Jakewharton has commented on twitter version 2.8.1 retrofit he has fixed the crash issue for 24 / 25 .. I have downgraded the dependencies but still the same. @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes.. Any other area which I should look?

Comment: Since more than 2 days, I have been facing and trying to fix this issue.

Comment: Please add in your question the link the twitter that akewharton made - this is due comments are temporal (*comments are deleted without notice*) and all vital information must be on the body of the question. Can you share to akewharton the link of this question? - he can surely help even more than I do. The related questions didn't help you?, I'm not familiar with retrofit, but, it might be possible the data you're processing is invalid somehow? - try test the with the same data in other devices...

Comment: ok, One more thing it weird, when I have disabled proguard. I different error.E: Failed to find provider info for com.education.comic.ebook.poptv_centralized_services.data.provider
A: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329] Throwing new exception 'length=9771; index=26087' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9771; index=26087
A: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at retrofit2.Call com.mpndbash.poptv.network.NetworkClassHandler$Companion.createRequestBody(int, java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap, boolean) 

UserLogin.validateCentralized()

Comment: Throwing new exception 'length=9771; index=26087' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9771; index=26087 A: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329] at retrofit2.Call ...
When this error come?

Comment: https://twitter.com/jakewharton/status/1242874287335313411?lang=en. @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes

Comment: **Please add all these details in your question** - you can doing so by doing click on [edit]. Look this: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9771; index=26087` = can you check why is the length is set to `9771`? - that's the error: somehow retrofit is reading an index outside of the length. The value of the index should be less or equal than the length.

Comment: No, I have not set any length response to read.